Expo React Native debugger not detecting compatible apps
I am rather new to React Native. I was working on a little hello-world project to get started. I am using the Expo framework, and I set up my project with the command npx create-expo-app@latest hello-world --template blank. I then used npx expo start to start my project, which worked fine, until I tried to run the debugger. I entered j - open debugger. But instead, it gave me this error:
Debug: No compatible apps connected. JavaScript Debugging can only be used with the Hermes engine.
I added "jsEngine": "hermes" under expo in app.json, but it changed nothing. Then I tried adding localhost:8081 to chrome://inspect, but interestingly, the React debugger didn't show up. Running expo-doctor also found no issues.
I am using Linux Mint and Brave. I also tried with Google Chrome, but it also didn't work.
Here is my app.json:
{
  "expo": {
    "jsEngine": "hermes",
    "name": "hello-world",
    "slug": "hello-world",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "orientation": "portrait",
    "icon": "./assets/icon.png",
    "userInterfaceStyle": "light",
    "splash": {
      "image": "./assets/splash.png",
      "resizeMode": "contain",
      "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
    },
    "ios": {
      "supportsTablet": true
    },
    "android": {
      "adaptiveIcon": {
        "foregroundImage": "./assets/adaptive-icon.png",
        "backgroundColor": "#ffffff"
      },
      "jsEngine": "hermes"
    },
    "web": {
      "favicon": "./assets/favicon.png"
    }
  }
}


Well, connecting my device first made the trick. I assumed I could debug from the web, but I was wrong.
